# How to split a variable based comma in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have made a ajax call to java servlet from where i am retrieving data and storing on success in data ..Here is my code...

```
            var s1="";
            var ticks ="";
            $('#view').click(function(evt){
                alert('hi');
                evt.preventDefault(); 
                $.ajax({
                        url:'getdata',
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function (data) {
                              console.log(data);
                              alert(data);
                        }

                    });

            });
```

Here is the values in data on success..

**[239, INCOMING, 30, INETCALL, 7, ISD, 55, LOCAL, 44, STD]**

Now as per my need i want this value to be in the variables..

**s1=239,30,7,55,44**
and **tics=INCOMING,INETCALL,ISD,LOCAL,STD**

Any help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: This looks like a great place to use JSON. Any chance that you can update the other end to return the data in a format that is easily used by Javascript?

Comment: what is the format of data?  is it an object or string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `data` variable is a string, i.e.:

```
"[239, INCOMING, 30, INETCALL, 7, ISD, 55, LOCAL, 44, STD]"
```

...then one way to achieve your desired result is to remove the first and last characters (the `[` and `]`) using `data.slice(1,-1)` and then `.split()` on `", "` to give you an array like this:

```
["239", "INCOMING", "30", "INETCALL", "7", "ISD", "55", "LOCAL", "44", "STD"]
```

And then put every second item into different arrays and `.join()` those arrays up into strings in the format you asked for:

```
var a = data.slice(1,-1).split(", "),
    s1 = [],
    tics = [],
    i = 0;
while (i < a.length) {
    s1.push(a[i++]);
    tics.push(a[i++]);
}
s1 = s1.join(",");
tics = tics.join(",");
```

I don't understand why your desired result is variables containing the values as comma-separated strings though. Obviously I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but to me it make more sense if `s1` and `tics` were arrays holding those values as separate elements (in which case you would obviously just omit the `.join(",")` statements from the end of the code I showed). But if you can update your server-side process to return JSON format you could return something like this:

```
{
    "s1" : [239, 30, 7, 55, 44],
    "tics" : ["INCOMING", "INETCALL", "ISD", "LOCAL", "STD"]
}
```

...and then jQuery would parse the JSON for you let you deal with that as an object with the properties already set as arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parts = string.split(",")

for (i = 0, l = parts.length; i < l; i += 2) {
    $alert(parts[i]);
}
```

try

Answer (score 0):

you can go through it with...

```
<script src="/include/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [239, "INCOMING", 30, "INETCALL", 7, "ISD", 55, "LOCAL", 44, "STD"]; 

var s1   = [];
var tics = [];

$.each(data,function(i,val)
{ 
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        s1.push(val); 
    }
    else
    {
        tics.push(val); 
    }
});

console.log('s1'); 
console.log(s1);  

console.log('----------');  

console.log('tics'); 
console.log(tics);  

</script>
```

That first comment is right, though... Can you change the format of how this is received to a more typical JSON format?

```
var data = [ "s1" : { 239, 30, 7, 55, 44 }, "tics" : { "incoming", "isd", "local", "std" } ];
```